# Webview stuck on mobile version of webside progress loading

Tags: android, html, webview, android-webview

I will release my second android application on Google Play soon.
But before relase I'm trying fix bugs.My application parse newspaper columnist article and show in application. I have 17 newspapers. Two of them bugy like same bug.
[image]

You see proggress dialog on middle. It's not mine application. It's mobile version of newspaper,Radikal...Although page loaded it is not disappear...This happen only my application and  on tablet browser, there is no problem

[image]

This is  Hurriyet newspaper's mobile version of site... It stuck like same. articles come after loading. But page stuck on loaded...

What problem can be ??

Note:If you want to see my application see, You can download it on omer-demirci.com/a.apk . After download  click menu click gazeteler and you well see newspaper names click hurriyet or radikal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem

> Webview by default comes with JavaSript false.

enabled it and solved

```
 webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```